# is there a tricky way to optimize this query

Tags: oracle, optimization, date

I'm working on a table that has `3008698` rows

`exam_date` is a `DATE` field.

But queries I run want to match only the month part. So what I do is:

```
select * from my_big_table where to_number(to_char(exam_date, 'MM')) = 5;
```

which I believe takes long because of function on the column.  Is there a way to avoid this and make it faster? other than making changes to the table?  `exam_date` in the table have different date values. like 01-OCT-10 or 12-OCT-10...and so on

Comment: The plans of your above SQL and harpo's SQL would help.  Make sure your tables statistics are up to date

Comment: Basic question but does the table actually have an index on exam_date at all??
(The fact that your performance differs when doing a range check suggests it does).

APCs comment about full-table scans is important - if your data is evenly spread through 12 months and you need to return 1/12th of 3008698 rows a full table scan is probably best - and also a lot of data.

One way to speed a full-scan up is by looking at Oracle's /*+ PARALLEL */ hint (which divides the full scan over your CPUs) - but there is the cost of re-assembling results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from my_big_table where MONTH(exam_date) = 5
```

oops.. Oracle huh?..

```
select * from my_big_table where EXTRACT(MONTH from exam_date) = 5
```

Comment: +1 Oracle has a couple of efficient date handling methods which you should use in WHERE because they can make use of the index in weird ways.

Comment: @learn_plsql  how much faster is this? Oracle still has to do a full table scan. Have you tried a Function Based Index? It may or may not help because the data has at most 12 distinct values.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know Oracle, but what about doing

```
WHERE exam_date BETWEEN first_of_month AND last_of_month
```

where the two dates are constant expressions.

Comment: doing: `exam_date between To_date('11/01/2010','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('11/30/2010','MM/DD/YYYY')` actually takes longer...

Answer (score 3):

Bear in mind that since you want approximately 1/12th of all the data, it may well be more efficient for Oracle to perform a full table scan anyway.  This may explain why performance was worse when you followed harpo's advice.

Why?  Suppose your data is such that 20 rows fit on each database block (on average), so that you have a total of 3,000,000/20 = 150,000 blocks.  That means a full table scan will require 150,000 block reads.  Now about 1/12th of the 3,000,000 rows will be for month 05.  3,000,000/12 is 250,000.  So that's 250,000 table reads if you use the index - and that's ignoring the index reads that will also be required.  So in this example the full table scan does a lot less work than the indexed search.

Comment: Hmmm, while I was typing up my answer you posted one which also starts "Bear in mind", making exactly the same point.  Great minds and all that ;)

Answer (score 3):

Bear in miond that there are only twelve distinct values for MONTH.  So unless you have a strongly clustered set of records (say if you use partitioining) it is possible that using an index is not necessarily the most efficient way of querying in this fashion.

I didn't find that using EXTRACT() lead the optimizer to use a regular index on my date column but YMMV:

```
SQL> create index big_d_idx on big_table(col3) compute statistics
  2  /

Index created.

SQL> set autotrace traceonly explain

SQL> select * from big_table
  2  where extract(MONTH from col3) = 'MAY'
  3  /

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3993303771

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |           | 23403 |  1028K|  4351   (3)| 00:00:53 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| BIG_TABLE | 23403 |  1028K|  4351   (3)| 00:00:53 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM INTERNAL_FUNCTION("COL3"))=TO_NUMBER('M
              AY'))

SQL>
```

What definitely can persuade the optimizer to use an index in these scenarios is building a function-based index:

```
SQL> create index big_mon_fbidx on big_table(extract(month from col3))
  2  /

Index created.

SQL> select * from big_table
  2  where extract(MONTH from col3) = 'MAY'
  3  /

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 225326446

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|Time    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |               | 23403 |  1028K|   475   (0)|00:00:06|
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| BIG_TABLE     | 23403 |  1028K|   475   (0)|00:00:06|
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | BIG_MON_FBIDX |  9361 |       |   382   (0)|00:00:05|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM INTERNAL_FUNCTION("COL3"))=TO_NUMBER('MAY'))

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function call means that Oracle won't be able to use any index that might be defined on the column.

Either remove the function call (as in harpo's answer) or use a function based index.